# Return true if certain elements of an array are nil

Tags: ruby, arrays, null

I'm working on an excel spreadsheet (with the spreadsheet gem), and for some rows there will be data missing in certain columns.

I want to return true if column 3 to the last column of a row (inclusive) all don't have values.

Here's my method:

```
def self.cells_empty(row)
   if row[3..-1] == nil
      return true
   else
      return false
   end
end
```

The method always return false however, even if for a specific row column 3 and all columns upto and including the last column are empty. When I mean empty, I mean empty/nil (nothing was ever written to those columns), not even an empty string ' '.

Comment: Is the index `3` in range of the array? Give an example of `row`.

Comment: A row is an array, columns are 0-indexed:
col 1: username, 
col 2: id, 
col 3: timestamp, 
col 4: data-type 1, 
col 5: data-type 2,
and so on @Yu Hao

Comment: An example would be is it like `[1,2,3]` or `[1,2,nil,nil,nil]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
row[2..-1].all?(&:nil?)
```

Comment: For fans of compact: `row[2..-1].compact.empty?` Will be slower, however.

Answer (score 0):

For any array `arr`, all values of `arr[i..j]` are `nil` if:

```
arr[i..j].compact.empty?
```